# WixManagedBootstrapperApplicationHost custom UI

Tags: wix, burn

I have created a msi which allows user to view license, select installation folder, and features to install. That all works well.

Now I need to create a bootstrapper that will check if framework 4.5 is installed, install it if not, and then install msi.

I can do this using WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLargeLicense, where I would install framework, and then execute msi with its own UI.

But what if I do not want to show two apps (msi over exe), but only one window?

Since my msi contains feature, standard bootstrapper does not provide interface where I can set features from msi, so I need to create a custom UI.

The problem is I do not quite understand how WixManagedBootstrapperApplicationHost works? I created a dll with new UI, and place it in Payload. When running the setup, when framework needs to be installed, WixManagedBootstrapperApplicationHost always invokes its own window which says:

```
Microsoft .NET Framework required for MyApp Setup. Click the "Accept and Install" button to accept the Microsoft .NET Framework license terms.
```

And after it completes installation of .NET Framework, then it invokes the UI that I Created in dll. Why would anyone want this kind of functionality, where my bootstrapper app contains totally different UI than the framework installation UI? Isn't the idea of bootstrapper with custom UI is to provide completely custom UI?

So, how can I provide my custom UI for that framework installation part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your own UI is C# and WPF? If your installing it on a machine without .Net then it's going to need to install .Net before it can show the WPF UI. I could be wrong but I'm sure that's unavoidable.

If you want to replace / modify the .Net install screen then this thread looks like it has the answer:

[Wix Burn: Basic UI handling if No Net Framework is there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21333045/wix-burn-basic-ui-handling-if-no-net-framework-is-there)

However if your saying the .Net install dialog is showing up over your UI at some point in installation then you need to set the Install command to "/q" which means quiet (no UI).

Comment: My software is build on v4.5, so I am restricted to supporting Vista or later. This means on every OS there will be framework installed (min v3). For this reason my custom Bootstrapper UI dll is built upon framework v3, so that I do not need to use BA prerequisites. However, seems that something is missing, since when I test on Vista, BA prerequisite always asks to install .NET Framework v4.5, although v3 is present. By BA prerequisite app I mean the exact window that is shown in a SO thread you posted link to. So, why does it show ir, if my BA needs framework v3, which is already present?

Comment: I think the bootstrapper.config file is what you need to be looking at. See the example of the one here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2011/10/28/introducing-managed-bootstrapper-applications.aspx You need to change the supported framework section I expect.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I already did configure bootstrapper.config, as in the link provided, but it still did not work. After I switched from v3.0 to v3.5, build UI targeting this framework, and configured bootstrapper.config to target this framework, it started worked fine. However, as soon as I rollback to v3.0 it starts crashing in presentationframework.dll. Strange...